# Log-Plots and PlotRange

Tags: plotting

Why does the `PlotRange` option in

```
list=Table[{x,Exp[Sqrt[x]]},{x,0,25}];
ListLogLogPlot[list,PlotRange->{0,10},Joined->True]
```

not work although there is no error-output? The same holds for `ListLogLogPlot`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you gave 0 as the lower limit and $\log (0)=-\infty$. If you look at the implementation of `ListLogLogPlot`, you'll see that somewhere along the line, the limits are converted to `{N@Log@min, N@Log@max}` and then plotted with `ListPlot` and the tick labels are tidied up. This is the specific line in the implementation:

```
logYPlotRange[{min_?Positive, max_?Positive}, r_] :=  N[{Log[min], Log[max]}]
```

So an extreme plot range will automatically be converted to something more "reasonable" that displays the plot. However, I do agree that a warning should be included. For instance, if you use -∞ as a plot range in `Plot`, you get the following warning:

> `Plot::prng:` Value of option `PlotRange -> {-∞,1}` is not `All`, `Full`, `Automatic`, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications. >>

If you want to set the limits for the axes from within `PlotRange`, then avoid 0. For example:

```
list = Table[{x, Exp[Sqrt[x]]}, {x, 0, 25}];
ListLogLogPlot[list, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {1, 50}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `If you look at the implementation of ListLogLogPlot`. Where did you take a look at the implementation? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen problems with this before but can't find the reference right now. So here is a solution:

```
list = Table[{x, Exp[Sqrt[x]]}, {x, 0, 25}];
ListLogLogPlot[list, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {1, 10}]
```

or

```
list = Table[{x, Exp[Sqrt[x]]}, {x, 0, 25}];
ListLogLogPlot[list, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {1, 10}}]
```

[image: loglogplot]

The problem of course could be called a bug, but in some sense it's also understandable that the plot range specification breaks when you put in a value of `0` for the argument on the `x` or `y` axis in a log-log plot. After all, the logarithm isn't defined there. It would be better if the function could recognize this and warn you, instead of ignoring the input altogether.