# Controlling range of ListLogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I'm having a problem where the following animation jumps around despite having `PlotRange` set. I don't have this problem with `ListPlot`, any suggestions what other options to set?

```
(* Spectrum of interleaved normal and bernoulli matrices *)
d = 128;
randNormal := 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {d, d}]/Sqrt[d];
randInteger := 
  N@Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@
      RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[d, .5]]/Sqrt[d/2];
svals = {};
mat = IdentityMatrix[d];
maxIters = 10;
For[i = 1, i <= maxIters, i += 1,
  mat = mat.randNormal.randInteger;
  AppendTo[svals, SingularValueList[mat]]
  ];

makeplot[k_] := 
 ListLogLogPlot[svals[[k]], PlotRange -> {{0, d}, {10^-10, 0}}]
animation = ListAnimate[makeplot /@ Range@maxIters]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> animation jumps around

I assume you are taking about the y-axis shaking?

I think this is because you used zero for the plot range and log(0) does not play well in the code.

If you change the zero, to another non zero value then it stops shaking. I also added image padding for safe measure.

```
makeplot[k_] := 
 ListLogLogPlot[svals[[k]], PlotRange -> {{0, d}, {10^-10, 100}}, 
  ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Compare to when using `PlotRange -> {{0, d}, {10^-10, 0}}`

[image]

It is possible this question is duplicate to [Log-Plots and PlotRange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17215/log-plots-and-plotrange)